# Magento 2.3.4 size swatch displayed for products with salable quantity 0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

We are using latest version of Magento 2.3.4.

Whenever a customer is creating an order a salable quantity for product (child of configurable product) is decreased - which is a correct behavior. The problem is that, a bought size is still available until order is shipped.

The customer can see size - while trying to add (just sold) size to bucket, he gets information that requested QTY is not available.

I would like to disable (grey out or cross out) unavailable size.

Can I achieve this using magento settings ? Or do I have to write a custom plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do multiple things:

1. Find the template of the dropdown and break into it with objectmanager and a custom (raw) query that checks the stock for the size and disables the option. This is fastest but bad especially if you don't have caching, the queries make the template slow to load.
2. Make a nice extension that overrides the templates trough xml file. Also override the php files (model/controller) and change the logic to acheive what you want. This is better practice. It has been done here i think, didnt test it myself:
   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/magento-2-2-how-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product
3. Find an extension from 3th party.

If you have a sample of code I can also help with it.